# Android Post Json Data to server using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Hello I have simple Json to post on server like below

```
{
    "Key":"KEY",
    "Token":"",
    "Data":
    {
         "Country": "India",
         "CountryCode":"IN",
         "MobileNumber":"+91111111111"
    }
}
```

How can i post this data to server Please help me out 
I have created Interface into this i have write

```
 @POST("/user/register/")
Call<Login> Registration(@Body Login login, Callback<Login> callBack);
```

is this ok? how i can call this?

I have Used it like

```
Login login = new Login();
        com.j2ml.casualtrack.pojo_Request.Data data = new com.j2ml.casualtrack.pojo_Request.Data();
        data.setMobileNumber("+911234567890");
        data.setCountry("India");
        data.setCountryCode("IN");
        login.setData(data);
        login.setToken("MY TOKEN KEY");
        login.setKey("");
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Registration in progress..", "Please wait...", false, false);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Urls.URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        service = retrofit.create(RestAPI.class);
        service.Registration(login, new Callback<Login>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<Login> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                System.out.println("Response: " + response.isSuccess());
                loading.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                System.out.println("ERROR ..."+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

But,I am getting this error

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2)
```

Comment: instead of posting one by one data just post all data at time .Create **POJO** of your json file .....use this link for **POJO** conversion of your **JSON** file:-http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Comment: bro please see edit comment i mention the link there...2 class created by that link use both class in your project...

Comment: not not yet i am not able to solve

Comment: please have look on edit answer......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code ..... for **retrofit**

```
 @POST("/user/register/")
Call<YourClass> createUser(@Body YourClass data);
```

instead of `YourClass` put your `POJO class` which have all data ....

and call retrofit for POST the data to the server.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://XXXXXXXXX.com")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();

YourClass you=new YourClass();
you.Key="new Key";//put all data like that in this class.

RegisterAPI api = retrofit.create(RegisterAPI.class);


Call<YourClass> call=api.createUser(you);
call.enqueue(new Callback<YourClass>() {});
```

Feel free to ask if any error come....

**Remove this line....**

```
com.j2ml.casualtrack.pojo_Request.Data Data = new com.j2ml.casualtrack.pojo_Request.Data();
```

and try this also

```
   data.setMobileNumber("+911234567890");
    data.setCountry("India");
    data.setCountryCode("IN");
```

instead of above use this one .....

```
    login.Data.setMobileNumber("+911234567890");
    login.Data.setCountry("India");
    login.Data.setCountryCode("IN");
```

enjoy coding.....

Comment: i have printed message like    System.out.println("Response: " + response.isSuccess());  System.out.println("MESSAGE : " + response.message()); but it display  Response: false
 MESSAGE : Not Acceptable

Comment: do you write the backhand code for the POST data into the server ?

Comment: use this link :-https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-retrofit-tutorial-to-insert-into-mysql-database/

Comment: is this problem from server side?

Comment: server have to handle the POST and PUT and DELETE data .....use above link for the post data into the server.

Comment: i am asking i am getting problem of MESSAGE : Not Acceptable that mean is there any problem in java code?

Comment: nope bcoz you enter the public void onResponse() method and getting message inside this method.

Comment: how i can print whole response? once i got printed response i can mark your answer as accepted answer

Comment: how i can print my full response?

Comment: if you get success = true than the whole response is on the database of your server. Start your back end i provide you the link .....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an object (assuming that your object is in a format like Test class .Here data is another object's list with attribute[country ,country code,mobilenumber] for each ).

```
class Test { 
@SerializedName("key")
int key;
@SerializedName("token")
string token;
@SerializedName("data")
ArrayList<Data> data; }
```

If you post this object to server it will take your required json like you have asked for.

```
{
"Key":"",
"Token":"",
"Data":
 {
     "Country": "",
     "CountryCode":"",
     "MobileNumber":""
 }
}
```

You can use @Body in that case like.
In service you can right something like,

```
@POST(URL)
public Call<Test> postTest(@Body Test instanceOfTest);
```

Hope this will help you.